# List only unique id's from 2 columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am building a basic private messaging system in Laravel and want to display a list of message threads between 2 users (to the user who is logged in) as a basic inbox.

At the moment I have all messages stored in 1 table. The table contains the "sender_id" and the "recipient_id" as well as the message contents.

To retrieve the list of messages to display in the inbox, I am currently doing this in the controller:

```
    //Authenticate the user
    $user = auth()->user()->id;

    $messagesSent = Message::where('sender_id', $user)->get();
    $messagesReceived = Message::where('recipient_id', $user)->get();

    $messageThreads = $messagesReceived->merge($messagesSent);
```

In the blade, to display the list of threads I am doing:

```
            <ul class="list-group">

            @foreach ($messageThreads as $message)

            @if($message->user->id != $user)

            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/messages/view/{{$message->user->id}}">{{$message->user->displayName}}</a></li>

            @else

            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/messages/view/{{$message->recipient->id}}">{{$message->recipient->displayName}}</a></li>

            @endif

            @endforeach

        </ul>
```

As expected, this is just displaying the names of the users which the user has messaged or received messages from as well as a link to the thread but if the user has had multiple messages between each other, their name will obviously display multiple times.

**Example of how its currently outputting**

- User 1 Thread
- User 1 Thread
- User 1 Thread
- User 2 Thread
- User 2 Thread
- User 3 Thread
- User 3 Thread

**How it should output:**

- User 1 Thread
- User 2 Thread
- User 3 Thread

I want to be able to make sure the name & link to the thread is only listed once.

I have tried using distinct() and unique() however because the sender_id & recipient_id are seperate columns, i still get duplicate results.

How would I able to overcome this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $recipientIds = Message::select('recipient_id')->where('sender_id', $user)->get()->pluck('recipient_id');
$senderIds = Message::select('sender_id')->where('recipient_id', $user)->get()->pluck('sender_id');


$userIds = array_unique(array_merge($recipientIds , $senderIds ));
$users = User::whereIn('id', $userIds)->keyBy('id');

// view
@foreach($users as $user) 
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/messages/view/{{$user->id}}">{{$user->displayName}}
@endforeach
```

Credit: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/list-only-unique-ids-from-2-columns

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
$user = auth()->user()->id;

$messageThreads = Message::where('sender_id', $user)->orWhere('recipient_id', $user)->get();
```

Basically, you were executing two similar queries on a single table, then merging results via PHP code. The solution above (untested) combines two queries into one, and thus merging happens on DB side.

Alternatively, you still can do this in PHP (here I assume your message records have primary key named "id"):

```
$messageThreads = $messageThreads->unique('id');
```

But this might mess with message order.

Comment: Thanks for this however it is still outputting the same amount of duplicates in the list.

Comment: Looks like you need to do additional grouping by thread ID, because your `$messageThreads` actually contains messages, not threads. I can't provide a code snippet because I don't know how your classes and table columns are named.